# Crud implementation in Eclipse, JSF, Java

Tags: java

I have a class (Vehicles) and I implemented CRUD operations. Delete works, update works, just create doesn't work.
What can I put instead of this create code?
P.S.: I use Eclipse
AND THIS IS FormMasini.java where I take from Vehicule.java dates and it will show in a JSF Form. The error appears at this line:  this.vehicul = new Vehicul();

```
package vehiculeFeaa;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICUL")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "VEHICUL_TYPE")
public abstract class Vehicul {

    @TableGenerator(name = "VEHICUL_GEN", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NUME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VALOARE", allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "VEHICUL_GEN")
    private int idVehicul;
    private String producator;

    public int getIdVehicul() {
        return idVehicul;
    }

    public void setIdVehicul(int idVehicul) {
        this.idVehicul = idVehicul;
    }

    public String getProducator() {
        return producator;
    }

    public void setProducator(String producator) {
        this.producator = producator;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public List<Vehicul> get(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}    


package masinifeaa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import vehiculeFeaa.Vehicul;

public class FormMasini {

    private Vehicul vehicul;
    private List<Vehicul>vehicule=new ArrayList<Vehicul>();
    public Vehicul getVehicul() {
        return vehicul;
    }
    public void setVehicul(Vehicul vehicul) {
        this.vehicul = vehicul;
    }
    public List<Vehicul> getVehicule() {
        return vehicule;
    }
    public void setVehicule(List<Vehicul> vehicule) {
        this.vehicule = vehicule;
    }
    private EntityManager em;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public FormMasini() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf=
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FirmeJPA");
        em=emf.createEntityManager();
        this.vehicule= em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vehicul v")
                .getResultList();
        if(!this.vehicule.isEmpty())
            vehicul=this.vehicule.get(0);
    }

    public void backVehicul(ActionEvent evt) {
    Integer idxCurent = this.vehicule.indexOf(vehicul);
    if(idxCurent > 0)
        this.vehicul=this.vehicule.get(idxCurent-1);
    }

    public void nextVehicul(ActionEvent evt) {
        Integer idxCurent = this.vehicule.indexOf(vehicul);
        if((idxCurent + 1) < this.vehicule.size())
             this.vehicul=this.vehicule.get(idxCurent + 1);

    }
    //Implementez actiunile CRUD
    public void deleteVehicul(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.vehicule.remove(this.vehicul);
        if(this.em.contains(this.vehicul)) {
            this.em.getTransaction().begin();
            this.em.remove(this.vehicul);
            this.em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
        if(!this.vehicule.isEmpty())
            this.vehicul=this.vehicule.get(0);
        else
            this.vehicul=null;
    }
    public void saveVehicul(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.em.getTransaction().begin();
        this.em.persist(this.vehicul);
        this.em.getTransaction().commit();

    }
    public void abandonVehicul(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(this.em.contains(this.vehicul))
            this.em.refresh(this.vehicul);
    }

        public void createVehicul(ActionEvent evt) {
                this.vehicul = new Vehicul();
                this.vehicul.setidVehicul(999);
                this.vehicul.setNume("New car");
                this.vehicule.add(this.vehicul);

}
```

Comment: What error? Show us the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing related to JSF or something else. You just can't instantiate a abstract class, thats basic java.